Complexity of training quantum neural network
In article Training a 3-Node Neural Network is NP-Complete, it was shown that training a neural network is NP-complete problem. In particular the authors proved NP-completeness of training for neural network consisting of neurons with linear threshold function (binary output based on value of linear combination of inputs). However, later works (e.g. On the Complexity of Training Neural Networks with Continuous Activation Functions and Complexity of Neural Network Training and ETR: Extensions with Effectively Continuous Functions) extended this result even to neurons with activation function belonging to certain class of continuous functions (including sigmoid ones).
On the other hand, the mentioned results do not rule out specific cases (depending on activation function of neurons, number of hidden layers, symetry of a neural network and input data sets), the training can be carried out for in polynomial time. Overall, to complexity of neural network training is still open question but we have to count with exponential time complexity in the worst case (as discussed in the first paper, even in case of approximate training - correct result with probability at least 2/3).
It is also well known that training of neural network is in fact an optimization problem. For such problem quantum computing provides several algorithms bringing up speed-up. So my question is whether there is similar analysis of training neural networks on a quantum computer. Any link to a paper will be appreciated.

in the title you ask about "training quantum neural network" but in the body you ask about "training neural networks on a quantum computers". Note that these are two potentially very different things (albeit terminology in the field is often confusing and/or misused, so it might depend on what you have in mind when writing "quantum neural network")

@glS: thank you for pointing this out. It really seems to be an important difference. We can train a classical neural network with a quantum optimization algorithm or to have the network completely in a quantum world. What I meant is a purely quantum case, i.e. data and neurons are in a quantum form.
